# Why does print ($a = a..c) produce: 1E0

Tags: perl

```
print (a..c) # this prints: abc  
print ($a = "abc") # this prints: abc

print ($a = a..c); # this prints: 1E0
```

I would have thought it would print: abc

```
use strict;
print ($a = "a".."c"); # this prints 1E0
```

Why? Is it just my computer?
edit: I've got a partial answer (the range operator .. returns a boolean value in scalar context - thanks) but what I don't understand is:
why does: print ($a = "a"..."c") produce 1 instead of 0
why does: print ($a = "a".."c")  produce 1E0 instead of 1 or 0

Comment: The problem here is list vs. scalar context. Will post a full answer sooner.

Comment: Understanding list/scalar context is fundamental to using Perl.  (There's also void context but that's not so important.)  mjd has an [introduction](http://perl.plover.com/context.html) and it's expounded further in [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).

Comment: “You will be miserable until you learn the difference between scalar and
list context, because certain operators  know which context they are in,
and return a list in contexts wanting a list but a scalar value in contexts
wanting a scalar.  (If this is true of an operation, it will be mentioned
in the documentation for that operation.)  In computer lingo, the
operations are overloaded on their return type.  But it’s a very simple
kind of overloading, based only on the distinction between singular and
plural values, and nothing else.” — *Programming Perl*

Comment: i (like to think i) understand the difference between list and scalar context, but, given that in scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value, why is 1 returned and not 0? why 1E0 and not 1?

Comment: “The value returned is either the null string for false or a sequence
number (beginning with `1`) for true.  The sequence number is reset for
each range encountered. The final sequence number in a range has the
string `E0` appended to it, which doesn’t affect its numeric value,
but gives you something to search for if you want to exclude the
endpoint.” — *Programming Perl*

Comment: mmmm, so 0..0 is true? print ($a = 0..0) produces 1E0. print (0..0) prints 0. So 0..0 is also false. Please could you give an example of "excluding the end point"?

Comment: is: print ($a = "a"..."c"); an example of "excluding the end point"? It produces 1 without the E0.   "If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation use three dots" is the right operand in this case "c"? So with 2 dots it tests the "c", and says it is false, and that it why the E0 appears. The E0 means false?

Comment: @DanD: No.  It tests that `"a"` is true: the range has started, that's why it produces 1.  Then, if using `..` and not `...`, in the same step, it tests that `"c"` is true: the range is over, that's why it adds `E0`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of subtle things going on here. The first is that `..` is really two completely different operators depending on the context in which it's called. In list context it creates a list of values (incrementing by one) between the given starting and ending points.

```
@numbers =  1  ..  3;  # 1, 2, 3
@letters = 'a' .. 'c'; # a, b, c (Yes, Perl can increment strings)
```

Because `print` interprets its arguments in list context

```
print 'a' .. 'c';    # <-- this
print 'a', 'b', 'c'; # <-- is equivalent to this
```

In scalar context, `..` is flip-flop operator. From [Range Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in perlop:

> It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left
>   operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand
>   is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

Assignment to a scalar value as in `$a = ...` creates scalar context. That means that the `..` in `print ($a = 'a' .. 'c')` is an instance of the flip-flop operator, not the list creation operator.

The flip-flop operator is designed to be used when filtering lines in a file. e.g.

```
while (<$fh>) {
    print if /first/ .. /last/;
}
```

would print all of the lines in a file starting with the one that contained `first` and ending with the one that contained `last`.

The flip-flop operator has some additional magic designed to make it easy to filter based on the line number.

```
while (<$fh>) {
    print if 10 .. 20;
}
```

will print lines 10 through 20 of a file. It does this by employing special case behavior:

> If either operand of scalar `..` is a constant expression, that
>   operand is considered true if it is equal (`==`) to the current input
>   line number (the `$.` variable).

The strings `a` and `c` are both constant expressions so they trigger this special case. They aren't numbers, but they're used as numbers (`==` is a numeric comparison). Perl will convert scalar values between strings and numbers as needed. In this case, both values nummify to 0. Therefore

```
print ($a = 'a' .. 'c');             # <-- this
print ($a = 0 .. 0);                 # <-- is effectively this
print ($a = ($. == 0) .. ($. == 0)); # <-- which is really this
```

We're getting close to the bottom of the mystery. On to the next bit. More from perlop:

> The value returned is either the empty string for false, or a sequence
>   number (beginning with 1) for true. The sequence number is reset for
>   each range encountered. The final sequence number in a range has the
>   string "E0" appended to it

If you haven't read any lines from a file yet, `$.` will be `undef` which is `0` in a numerical context. `0 == 0` is true, so the `..` returns a true value. It's the first true value, so it's `1`. Because *both* the left-hand and right-hand sides are true the first true value is also the last true value and the `E0` "this is the last value" suffix is appended to the return value. *That* is why `print ($a = 'a' .. 'c')` prints `1E0`. If you were to set `$.` to a non-zero value the `..` would be false and return the empty string.

```
print ($a = 'a' .. 'c'); # prints "1E0"
$. = 1;
print ($a = 'a' .. 'c'); # prints nothing
```

The very final piece of the puzzle (and I might be going too far now) is that the assignment operator returns a value. In this case that's the value assigned to `$a`<sup>1</sup> -- `1E0`. This value is what is ultimately spit out by the `print`.

<sub>1: Technically, the assignment produces a lvalue for the item assigned to. i.e. it returns an lvalue for the variable `$a` which then evaluates to `1E0`.</sub>

Comment: wow nice explanation. It's going to take me a while to get my head around all this. The last bit is especially cool imo.

Answer (score 12):

It's a matter of list context vs. scalar context, as explained in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator
>   maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine
>   that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.
>   Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again. It doesn't become false till the next time the range operator
>   is evaluated. It can test the right operand and become false on the
>   same evaluation it became true (as in awk), but it still returns true
>   once. If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next
>   evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In
>   all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

[snip]

> The final sequence number in a range has the string "E0" appended to
>   it, which doesn't affect its numeric value, but gives you something to
>   search for if you want to exclude the endpoint.

**EDIT** in response to DanD man's comment:

I find it a bit hard to digest too; frankly, I rarely use the `..` operator, and even more rarely in scalar context.  But for example, the expression `5..10` in an input loop implicitly compares to the current value of `$.` (that's part of the description that I didn't quote; see the manual).  On lines 5 through 9, it yields a true value (experiment shows that it's a number, but the documentation doesn't say so).  On line 10, it yields a number with `"E0"` appended to it -- i.e., it's in exponential notation, but with the same value it would have without the `"E0"`.

The point of the `"E0"` tweak is to let you detect whether you're in a specified range *and* to flag the last line in the range for special treatment.  Without the `"E0"`, you wouldn't be able to treat the final match specially.

An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my $dotdot = 2..4;
    print "On line $., 2..4 yields \"$dotdot\"\n";
}
```

Given 5 lines of input, this prints:

```
On line 1, 2..4 yields ""
On line 2, 2..4 yields "1"
On line 3, 2..4 yields "2"
On line 4, 2..4 yields "3E0"
On line 5, 2..4 yields ""
```

This lets you detect whether a line is inside or outside the range *and* when it's the last line in the range.

But scalar `..` is probably more commonly used just for its boolean result, often in one-liners; for example, `perl -ne 'print if 2..4'` will print lines 2, 3, and 4 of whatever input you give it.  It's deliberately similar to `sed -n '2,4p'`.

Comment: Just had some functional programming (Clojure), so I thought I tried some methods. print $a = join("", a..c) seems to do the trick nicely (a..c creates a list, which join puts in a sequence, using the empty string in between the items, this gets assigned to $a, and therefore printed...)

Comment: Thank you. I find it hard to digest what perlop is saying here.

Answer (score 10):

The answer can be found by consulting perldoc's [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) page:

> Binary ".." is the range operator, which is really two different operators depending on the context. In list context, it returns a list of values counting (up by ones) from the left value to the right value...

This is the familiar usage, which is invoked by `print "a" .. "c";` because arguments to functions are evaluated in list context. (If they were evaluated in scalar context, then `print @list` would print the size of `@list`, which is almost definitely not what people usually want.)

> **In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value.** The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine that contains it. **It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.** It doesn't become false till the next time the range operator is evaluated. It can test the right operand and become false on the same evaluation it became true (as in awk), but it still returns true once. If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

It goes into further detail, but the bolded sections are the important parts to understanding how the operator works. Scalar context is forced by `$a =`, i.e. assignment to a scalar lvalue. If you did `@a =`, it would print what you expect.

Note that `"a" .. "b"` doesn't produce the string `"abc"`, it produces the list `("a", "b", "c")`. You will get similar results if you used the list (though the value printed when the list is forced into scalar context will differ).

Comment: I'm finding it a bit hard to digest what perlop is saying here. In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. Ok so it's either going to be 1 or 0. Is there any way of getting it to print 0e0 ?

Comment: Thank you. I find it hard to digest what perlop is saying here. $a is false before the assignment has taken place. Something is assigned to it. Then it becomes true...This makes the boolean state of the .. operator true? The boolean state is represented by the number 1, which is assigned to the $a? and then it bolts E0 on the end...because it wanted to confuse noobs.

Comment: @DanDman - It's meant to be used in a loop reading lines from a file: `while(<FILE>) { print if 3 .. 6 }` prints the third through sixth lines of `FILE`.

Comment: $_ = "AAA"; print if 3..6 # this prints nothing so wouldn't: while(<FILE>) {print if 3..6}} also print nothing?

Comment: @DanDman - No. `3..6` compares against `$.`, which is a special variable that records the line number of the last line read from a file. So in the `while(<FILE>)` loop, every time it loops, `$.` goes up one. At the third line `$.` is 3, which is equal to 3, so `3..6` returns `"1"`. The next line, it returns `"2"`, then `"3"`, then `"4e0"`, indicating that it's the sixth (`$.` is 6) and last line. It returns false again starting at the seventh line. `if 0..3` is roughly the same as `if $. >= 3 and $. <= 6`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. I learnt a lot from you. Your answer made Michael Carman's easier to understand.